# Hot reload vs hot restart in Android Studio with Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm testing my Flutter starter app on virtual as well as physical device. The problem is that the app doesn't update on the screen while hot-reloading (this is configured to work at every file-save), but only on hot-restart. On the screenshot this corresponds to the right button, not the left.

Is it normal or is something wrong?

[image]

Just in case, this is the contents of my `main.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
            child: Text('Hi Everybody!'),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage(
              'images/diamond.png',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: i think you are writing everything inside main function. otherwise add your code.

Comment: @MSARKrish Yes, I'm writing everything inside `main` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing everything inside main function. so hot reload is not working.

They mentioned this in [Flutter Documentaion](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload#recent-ui-change-is-excluded)

> As a general rule, if the modified code is downstream of the root
>   widget’s build method, then hot reload behaves as expected. However,
>   if the modified code won’t be re-executed as a result of rebuilding
>   the widget tree, then you won’t see its effects after hot reload.

so you need to write your code below root widget.

Write code like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
            child: Text('Hi Everybody!'),
          ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Image(
        image: AssetImage(
          'images/diamond.png',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```